# highcharts, no data position

Tags: highcharts, angular2-highcharts

I'm configuring my chart in highcharts and everything works fine but the noData position.

This is my options:

```
optionsChart = {
    chart: {
    type: 'bar'
  },
  lang: {
    noData: 'No data available'
  },
  noData: {
    position: {
      align: 'end'
    }
  }
}
```

the text is setted but it's not aligned, how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It work with `left`, `center` or `right`

```
noData:{
    position:{
        align:'right'
    }
},
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/core972/tq4wxjvb/)

Comment: Wow, I tried some issues and forgot to try "right"... thank you so much